# I have master privileges for Group in Git but I don't see an option to create sub group under that parent group

Tags: gitlab

I want to sub groups my project under main group. Though I have master privileges for parent Group in GitLab but I don't see an option to create sub group under that parent group. am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to be an owner of the group to create subgroups ([see `Create subgroup`](https://gitlab.com/help/user/permissions.md#group-members-permissions)).

Comment: @RahulJain glad to hear! Please mark the answer as correct :)